# How do I compare 2 integers without getting warnings?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a variable `Player1Visits` which is declared as `int`.

If I try to compare this to 1 using `Player1Visits == 1` I get the warning comparison between integer and pointer.  Should I be using a different type?

Comment: It is vital to know what language you are talking about, sounds like it could be C, please tag the question.

Also copying the declaration would help since it sounds like Player1Visits is actually declared as a pointer

Comment: Instead of using `*pointer` when comparing I suggest changing the type to `int` instead of `int*`. I don't think that you want a pointer to an int in your program code. If you wanted that, you'd understand the compiler warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you mean to compare:

```
*Player1Visits == 1
```

Answer (score 4):

I would double-check what Player1Visits is declared as; if you're getting that compiler warning, it is almost certainly not an `int`. Likely possibilities include what @aronchick said, where Player1Visits is an `int*` (a pointer to an int), so you want to compare using:

```
*Player1Visits == 1
```

Another possibility is that Player1Visits is some kind of object with an `int` *property*, where you want to figure out what property name you want and call:

```
[Player1Visits someIntProperty] == 1
```

(This last assumes you're using Objective-C, which is (I believe) a not-unreasonable assumption given your choice of IDE.)

Answer (score 3):

You haven't declared it as `int`, the compiler warning gives that away. Perhaps you've declared it as `NSInteger *Player1Visits;` or `int *Player1Visits;`.

If you declared it that way, remove the `*`.